# Arguments undefined calling anonymous function inside axios catch using reactjs-redux

Tags: reactjs, try-catch, axios, anonymous-function

I'm trying to create a react redux middleware to call rest api, so far everything is ok when I got 2xx status but I have a problem with other status, the ones that fell into the catch, during the debug I can see the content of the error variable before call my function but when catch call my on_error function defined in my action file the argument passed are undefined, the code is super simple

**middleware/api.js**

```
const { method, url, data, on_success, on_error } = action.payload;

axios({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    headers: headers
})
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch(on_success(response));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(on_error(error.response))
        dispatch(on_error(error.response));
    });
```

**action/auth.js**

```
export const authError = (error_response) => {
    console.log(error_response);
    return {
        type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
        payload: errorCodesMessage(error_response.status)
    }
};

export const logInUser = (username, password) => ({
    type: 'API',
    payload: {
        method: 'post',
        url: API_AUTH_URL,
        on_success: ({ data }) => setToken(data),
        on_error: ({ error_response }) => authError(error_response),
        data: JSON.stringify({
            password: password,
            username: username
        })
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameter as an object

`on_error: ({error_response}) => authError(error_response)`

Instead, pass it directly

`on_error: (error_response) => authError(error_response)`

Or if the above method is not a pattern that you or your team follows then change the way you are passing parameters to the callback:

middleware/api.js

`on_error({ error_response: error.response })`

Comment: @rash-tay Thanks!!